# log4j - Empty log file -

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

I have a Java Application with this following log4j configuration properties, called log4j-DEV.properties:

```
################################################################
# Root logger option
###############################################################
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, file,stdout

###############################################################


###############################################################
# Logger response
###############################################################
log4j.logger.response=ALL, proxyLog
log4j.additivity.response=false 

###############################################################



#############################################################
# APPENDER
############################################################# 

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log\\application.log
log4j.appender.file.Threshold = ALL
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold = ALL
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.proxyLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.proxyLog.Threshold = ALL
log4j.appender.proxyLog.File=C:\\log\\proxyLog.log
log4j.appender.proxyLog.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.proxyLog.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.proxyLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.proxyLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I use Tomcat as Application Server and I launch it with parameter  *-Dlog4j.configuration="log4j-DEV.properties"*

When application starts, the file  *C:\log\application.log* and *C:\log\proxyLog.log* are created but are empty although application writes log with instruction:

```
Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
log.info("Test log");
```

What is wrong?

Thanks all

Comment: I write the log appender file like: 
log4j.appender.toFile.File = logs/resourcepie_logfile.html,
notice the forward leaning single slash, and i get a log file

Comment: @svarog I changed the path using forward leaning but the result it's the same: the file is created but it's empty.

Comment: could you provide a code sample with imports of how you're using the logger ?

Comment: I solved the issue changing the code in this way:
 `Logger logger = null;` 
`logger = Logger.getRootLogger();` 
`logger.info("TEST");`

Comment: If you can find out why exactly it works like that, then please post it as an answer.
btw, i'm using log manager like: private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName());
and i'm kind of curious as of why it works

Answer (score 3):

I changed my code from:

```
Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
log.info("Test log");
```

to

```
Logger logger = null; 
logger = Logger.getRootLogger(); 
logger.info("TEST");
```

The log4j configuration was fine, I changed the behavior of application in order to use directly log4j classes and now the log appears correctly.

Thanks

Comment: I was using sl4j and it happened to be more hard to use than l4j directly!