# Log4j files are empty

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to use log4j to log different content to different files. Therefore i created the following config file (at the moment everything gets written to the console aswell):

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.debugLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.debugLog.File=logs/debug.log
log4j.appender.debugLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.debugLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

log4j.appender.reportsLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.reportsLog.File=logs/reports.log
log4j.appender.reportsLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.reportsLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.category.reportsLogger=DEBUG, reportsLog
log4j.additivity.reportsLogger=false

log4j.category.debugLogger=DEBUG, debugLog
log4j.additivity.debugLogger=false
```

and I use the loggers a follows:

```
public class Main {
    private static final Logger debugLog = Logger.getLogger("debugLog");
    private static final Logger perfLog = Logger.getLogger("reportsLog");

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        debugLog.debug("Starting");
        perfLog.debug("Starting");
    }
}
```

The problem: The log files get created but are empty. only the output at the console gets displayed.
Do I have my config file wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882310/log4j-empty-log-file

Comment: with this answer everything gets logged everywhere.

Comment: Your category is called `debugLogger`, but you are creating the logger with `debugLog` (same for *reports*).

Comment: Ah stupid ... If you want you can post it and im going to accept it...